# Zend Barcode Library Not Working Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using the Codigniter Framework, and the Zend Barcode Library to generate barcodes.

My code for generating barcodes works in localhost, but when on the server it shows a blank page.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: I believe Zend Barcode requires [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), which your live server may not have installed.

Comment: how do i  know what are the libraries installed in server? how do check?

Comment: `php -m` from the command line or `phpinfo();` from inside a script.

Comment: I have checked phpinfo(); but same blank  page show

Comment: Put `phpinfo();` in a separate file by itself so other code around won't cause errors.

Comment: ok, but  GD Library was installed because PDF files are created in my server

Comment: any other important library for zend bar code generation?

Comment: Check your web server error logs, it will likely contain the PHP error details.

Comment: where can i see that error log?

Comment: Depends how your server is configured. Often under `/var/log/` somewhere.

Comment: ok. 
any other important library for zend bar code generation?

Comment: I dunno, go read the docs. :)

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a bit, would you please post a **[Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** so that we can take a look at your code and see why it's not working?

Comment: private function set_barcode($code){
        $this->load->library('Zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
        $file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text' => $code), array());
        $store_image = imagepng($file,FCPATH."assets/barcode/{$code}.png");
        return $code.'.png';
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have zend framework in production for many application. To solve your issue you have to clean buffer before render your generated barcode :

```
ob_end_clean
```

Example :

```
  $barcodeOptions = array('text' => "TEXT-BARCODE");
    $rendererOptions = array();

        ob_end_clean();
    \Zend\Barcode\Barcode::factory(
    'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    )->render();
```